# What is the correct html element to present information like Username, Primary Email, Phone number?

Tags: html

If you want to present the user's username, email, etc on an Account Page what is the correct element to show things like:

```
<h3>User Account<h3>

Username:
  a-user-name
Primary email:
  bla@bla.com
Phone:
  1111111111
```

Would `<dl><dt><dd>` be a good solution or just plain old `<p>` with brakes, maybe a `<div>`,
maybe even use `h4`s for 'Username' and 'Primary email' and `<p>` or `<div>` for the values?

What is best for accessibility?

Thank you

Comment: There is a lot of methods that you can do it, use what you like more

Comment: @ch1puha This is a question about accessibility. There is not a "lot" of ways that'll tell a screen reader what it is, unless you manually add `aria-role`, `aria-label` etc

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `<a>` tag containing `href="mailto:"`.
If this will be an address you can use the [`<address>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/address) tag as well.

Example from MDN:

```
<p>Contact the author of this page:</p>

<address>
  <a href="mailto:jim@rock.com">jim@rock.com</a><br>
  <a href="tel:+13115552368">(311) 555-2368</a>
</address>
```

This will be friendly for screens readers and such.

Comment: It's more like for an account info page that only the user can see. and the email has an edit icon next to it. But address could work, just not sure